# Entity Framework: check if a trigger exists

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework v 6.1.3 and I want to check if a trigger exists on the database.

I have a piece of SQL that I am running, but the check for trigger existence doesn't work. It works just fine in SQL Server Management Studio when run against the same database. It just doesn't find the trigger when run from inside EF / .NET

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE [name] = 'DbTrigAuditHandler_CreateAlterDrop')
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @sql = ' DYNAMIC SQL CREATE TRIGGER ' 

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

As a result I get an exception because the object already exists.

I have two questions.

1. Why might this be happening?
2. Is there a way to check inside EF?

Cheers

Comment: Can you put it in a Stored Procedure and just call that Stored Proc from EF?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put it in an sp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this would be the case, but when I replaced my calling code:
From

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

To

```
var sql = File.ReadAllText(path);
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
```

The code executes as expected.